# SAP Connector using Oracle JDBC and virtual host name "oracle" gives: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection():

Tags: oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc, connector, jco

Using a working JDBC connect string for a connect to a remote Oracle database using Oracle JDBC like

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@myremotehost:1521:mysid
```

and mapping it inside SAP Connector with nomenclature

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@&lt;virtual host name&gt;:&lt;virtual Port&gt;:mysid
```

with

```
<virtual host name> = oracle
<virtual Port>= 61521
```

resulting in

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:61521:mysid
```

will end up with error

> **org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.impl.DriverDataSource@45d186af**

To check if the issue is related to a problem in the Oracle JDBC Driver we

1. Installed SAP JDK 8 on the remote database machine
2. Using Maven to create a standalone Spring-Boot/Spring-JDBC/HikariCP/Oracle JDBC JAR reflecting the stack of SAP Connector / SAP VM using with iFlows
3. Tested the JAR with connect string successfully

   ```
   jdbc:oracle:thin:@myremotehost:1521:mysid
   ```
4. add on remote database machine to file /etc/hosts an entry like

   ```
   oracle   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
   ```

   where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the IP of machine "myremotehost"
5. Tested the recreated JAR with new connect string successfully

   ```
   jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:mysid
   ```
6. Replacing "oracle" as virtual host name by "myoracle" like below fixed the issue with SAP Connector

   ```
   jdbc:oracle:thin:@myoracle:61521:mysid
   ```

According to our finding we think the error is caused inside SAP Connector using Java `String.replace()` function replacing inside connect string

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:61521:mysid
```

- Any occurance of "oracle" (virtual host name) by the remote host name "myremotehost"
- Any occurance of "61521"  (virtual port number) by the remote host port "1521"

ending up with a connect string like

```
jdbc:myremotehost:thin:@myremotehost:1521:mysid
```

which is invalid because the first occurrence of "oracle" in original connect string is required to resolve classes giving the seen error because no connection could be established.

For Developers of the SAP Connector at SAP: Valid workaround in the Java code of SAP Connector would be using regexp or restrict replacement for substring right of at-Sign "@" in connect string so that class resolving is still possible ;-)

kind regards
Frank Scherie

Expectation:

SAP fixes the issue and creates a bug/note for the issue

Comment: Apologies if I have missed it - but what is your question to the Stack Overflow community? (This reads more like a bug report intended for SAP Support.)

Comment: If you have a solution or workaround that you want to share, you are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - using the Q&A format: state the problem in your question, then provide the solution/workaround as an answer (not as part of the question).

Comment: which SAP product do you use? is it about SAP JCo connector?